# Resque web front end - Internal Server Error - RuntimeError - ERR operation not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Any guesses why I get this internal server error when going to the Resque front end? I have it working locally but this occurs on my staging server:

resque.yml

```
staging: redis://localhost:6379
```

resque.rb

```
path = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/yaml/resque.yml")[Rails.env]
uri = URI.parse(path)
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

Resque.redis = REDIS
```

--

```
RuntimeError - ERR operation not permitted:
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:47:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:421:in `block in smembers'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:420:in `smembers'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-namespace-1.0.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:213:in `method_missing'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque.rb:193:in `queues'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/queues.erb:39:in `block in singletonclass'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/queues.erb:65533:in `instance_eval'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/queues.erb:65533:in `singletonclass'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/queues.erb:65531:in `__tilt_6842620'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `cached_evaluate'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:343:in `render'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:302:in `erb'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:105:in `partial'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/overview.erb:3:in `block in singletonclass'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/overview.erb:65533:in `instance_eval'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/overview.erb:65533:in `singletonclass'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server/views/overview.erb:65531:in `__tilt_6842620'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `cached_evaluate'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:343:in `render'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:302:in `erb'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:124:in `show'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Server>'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:52:in `block in route_eval_with_newrelic'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:255:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:250:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:51:in `route_eval_with_newrelic'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:41:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/prefix.rb:26:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.1/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/remotipart-1.0.2/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:241:in `fetch'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
 /apps/eg/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
 <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
cache: [GET /app/resque/overview] miss
```

**UPDATE:**

More simply I can get the error with:

$ redis-cli ping

(error) ERR operation not permitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably worked out from the error message, it's a permissions issue. Do you have any auth set up on Redis on your staging env?

Comment: No that I'm aware of. I looked through the .conf file and didn't see anything. I also discovered this: redis-cli ping
(error) ERR operation not permitted

Comment: I hadn't reloaded the conf file properly after commenting out requirepass. Reboot solved it (after removing requirepass). Thanks.